# What is the use of fork() - ing before exec()?

Tags: c, unix, process

In *nix systems, processes are created by using fork() system call. Consider for example, init process creates another process.. First it forks itself and creates the a process which has the context like init. Only on calling exec(), this child process turns out to be a new process. So why is the intermediate step ( of creating a child with same context as parent ) needed? Isn't that a waste of time and resource, because we are creating a context ( consumes time and wastes memory ) and then over writing it?

Why is this not implemented as allocating a vacant memory area and then calling exec()? This would save time and resources right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intermediate step enables you to set up shared resources in the child process without the external program being aware of it. The canonical example is constructing a pipe:

```c
// read output of "ls"
// (error checking omitted for brevity)
int pipe_fd[2];
pipe(&pipe_fd);
if (fork() == 0) {       // child:
    close(pipe_fd[0]);   // we don't want to read from the pipe
    dup2(pipe_fd[1], 1); // redirect stdout to the write end of the pipe
    execlp("ls", "ls", (char *) NULL);
    _exit(127);          // in case exec fails
}
// parent:
close(pipe_fd[1]);
fp = fdopen(pipe_fd[0], "r");
while (!feof(fp)) {
    char line[256];
    fgets(line, sizeof line, fp);
    ...
}
```

Note how the redirection of standard output to the pipe is done in the child, between `fork` and `exec`. Of course, for this simple case, there could be a [spawning API](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/posix_spawn.html) that would simply do this automatically, given the proper parameters. But the `fork()` design enables arbitrary manipulation of per-process resources in the child — one can close unwanted file descriptors, modify per-process limits, drop privileges, manipulate signal masks, and so on. Without `fork()`, the API for spawning processes would end up either extremely fat or not very useful. And indeed, the process spawning calls of competing operating systems typically fall somewhere in between.

As for the waste of memory, it is avoided with the [*copy on write*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) technique. `fork()` doesn't allocate new memory for the child process, but points the child to the parent's memory, with the instructions to make a copy of a page only if the page is ever written to. This makes `fork()` not only memory-efficient, but also fast, because it only needs to copy a "table of contents".

Answer (score 2):

This is an old complaint. Many people have asked *Why `fork()` first?* and typically they suggest an operation that will both create a new process from scratch and run a program in it. This operation is called something like `spawn().`

And they always say, *Won't that be faster?*

And in fact, every system other than the Unix family *does* go the "spawn" way. Only Unix is based on `fork()` and `exec().`

But it's funny, Unix has always been much faster than other full-featured systems. It has always handled way more users and load.

And Unix has been made even faster over the years. Fork() no longer really duplicates the address space, it just shares it using a technique called [*copy-on-write*.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) (A very old fork optimization called [`vfork()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28operating_system%29#Vfork_and_page_sharing) is also still around.)

Drink the [Kool-Aid.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kool-Aid)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how the *init* process works on a kernel in terms of forking but to answer you question of why you need to call **fork** then **exec** is simply because once you **exec** there is no turning back.

If you check out the documentation [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/execlp.html), it essentially requires a new process to be spawned (the **fork** call) in order for the parent process to resume control and either **wait** for it to finish or sit as a daemon probably would.

Answer (score 0):

> Only on calling exec(), this child process turns out to be a new
>   process.

Not really. After a fork, you already have new process, even not that much different from its parent. There are some cases where no exec need to follow a fork.

> So why is the intermediate step ( of creating a child with same
>   context as parent ) needed?

One reason would be because it is an efficient way to create the whole shebang. Cloning is usually less complex than creating from scratch.

> Isn't that a waste of time and resource, because we are creating a
>   context ( consumes time and wastes memory ) and then over writing it?

It is not a waste of time and resource as most of this resource is virtual, due to the copy on write mechanism used. Moreover, it is incorrect to state the created context is overwritten. Nothing is rewritten given the fact nothing was actually written in the first place. That's the whole point of COW. "Only" the process address space (code, heap and stack) are substituted, not overwritten. A lot of the process context is partially or totally preserved, including environment, file descriptors, priority, ignored signals, current and root directory, limits, various masks, processor bindings, privileges and several other things foreign to the process address space.

Comment: Cloning might be less complex than creating from scratch, but if we're forking with the goal of running a different program, we have to `exec` after fork. This `exec` will blow all the effort that went into cloning, so the question posed by the OP is why did we bother to clone in the first place?

Comment: @user4815162342 Read my reply closer. The only thing that is substituted with an exec, the process address space, cost almost no effort to clone as it is copy on write. The kernel side process context which is what really matters is preserved with an exec. There is no effort blown.

Comment: Good point, I skipped over your last paragraph. I still wonder about the "almost no effort" part. It would be interesting to compare forked and fork-free process creation on the same operating system.

Comment: I believe the fork system call is always much faster than either exec of posix_spawn. Moreover, posix_spawn is likely to be implemented by sharing most or all of the exec code, and probably uses too a part of the fork code to avoid the requirement to maintain two code path to do the same thing. The only point where posix_spawn indeed makes a difference is where the virtual memory resource itself limited, i.e. on systems with too little a swap area.

Comment: Popular Unix systems implement `posix_spawn` [in terms of fork+exec](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/posix/spawni.c;h=f92b44f8065fe5f0af87e64d4e2d99db6d9a4cca;hb=HEAD#l108), so a comparison of the two is not useful. But it doesn't [have to](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/mach/hurd/spawni.c;h=867579de5579d6087e80280eb7523a54fafce533;hb=HEAD#l51) be implemented that way. The very existence of `vfork` attests that, at least historically, `fork` was occasionally considered problemetic.

Comment: Developers indeed do not have to implement it that way but the performance gain, if any, that a re-implementation might provide probably does not worth the effort and the risks. There is no much point fixing things that are not broken and work find. By the way, vfork is generally not a whole new implementation but just a system call entry that share most of the same underlying kernel code with fork.